# Detect first user interaction on document

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I am trying to implement a PWA with a story feature, similar to Instagram, Snapchat, Facebook and co. After opening the application, it should instantly start playing videos. I have to do this using pure javascript. Conceptually, it looks like this:

```
let video = document.getElementById("story");
video.play();
```

Upon loading the page the first time, chrome throws an error and states that autoplay is disabled before any user interaction (which makes sense).

How can I detect this **first user interaction**? Do I have to listen to every possible event or is there an easier way, maybe a hierarchy of events?

Comment: Not sure about any hierarchy of events. You'll probably be OK with click (or mousedown), keydown, scroll, mousemove, touchstart, auxclick, and wheel. (more here  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element#Events). Might even work with window.resize and window.orientationchange (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window#Events).

Answer (score 0):

In 2022 at iROOMit we've developed `@iroomit/page-interaction-listener` that makes achieving this a simple one-liner: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@iroomit/page-interaction-listener

Simply call the library with the code you want to delay until after any user interaction as a function:

```
addListener(() => {
    // code to delay
});
```

Live example on https://www.iroomit.com/ (wait a second before hovering the page and observe the network requests made on hover)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33400374)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the HTML DOM API now supports this with `navigator.userActivation.hasBeenActive`.

More information at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UserActivation

Answer (score -1):

What you want may be https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mousemove_event. Looking at examples of this online will help.